# C# add a Table<T> into an existing DataContext Instance

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Is it possible that I can add `Table<T>` dynamiclly to an exisitng DataContext Insance in LinqToSQL?

Here is my case:
   I have several classsed which are using [Test] attribute to declared as Table,  I want to allow user to create the corresponding SQL Server tables during run-time.  I understand that If I inherit the DataContext class,  I can add member
    Table customers;
in the class and it will automaticly create such a table at the backend database. 
However, the problem is that whether I can add Table during run-time to a DataContext class which help me to create the correspondgin SQL Server Table corresponding to T.

Comment: What do you mean? Adding the table to the database? Adding a representation of an already existing database table? Adding an in-memory only Table object?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible. Linq2Sql reads Meta information from your Attributes and store them in a cache - for all instances of your context.

The only chance you have is to generate those classes in Memory and then emit them into a *new* AppDomain. Sounds hard, but it isn't. But how do you want to access those classes? Reflection?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call GetTable<T>(); on the DataContext. It will read the attributes on T at that time.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to add tables generated at run time to the dbml. If you open the dbml file in a text editor, you can see that dbml contains the column definition. At run time you can dynamically generate this file with the new table fields and add this dbml to the `.csproj` project file. This will auto generate the designer classes.

```
<Table Name="dbo.VijaysToDos" Member="VijaysToDos">
    <Type Name="VijaysToDo">
      <Column Name="id" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="column1" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(255)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="column2" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(255)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="column3" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(255)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Column Name="last_Updated" Type="System.DateTime" DbType="DateTime" CanBeNull="true" />
    </Type>
</Table>
```