# Creating SQL Server CE DataContext with Tables at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I am building a library for Windows Phone 8 which requires local databases. Here is my understanding of how the LINQ-to-SQL works and creates database:

- `DataContext` object is created from the corresponding class.
- When CreateDatabase() method is called, it reads the connection string and the members of type `Table` from the DataContext object.
- The method creates database at given location and creates tables corresponding to the members of DataContext object.

Now, the `DataContext` class has to be hard typed. As I am building a library, I wouldn't know which tables the user will need. Obviously, I cannot use the hard typed `DataContext`. Moreover, `CreateTable()` method doesn't exist in this scenario. If I simply start using `GetTable` method, I get `Table does not exist` error.

The question is, how do I get create tables without using a hard typed `DataContext`?

P.S.: My situation is sort of similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470106/c-sharp-add-a-tablet-into-an-existing-datacontext-instance).

Comment: I think this is the closes you can get: http://stackoverflow.com/q/582221/861716

Comment: @Gret Thanks for pointing that out. Doesn't seem to suite my scenario though. I don't even know if Windows Phone has enough freedom. I am thinking of accepting whole `DataContext` from the user of library before issuing call to `CreateDatabase()` method. Would that work?

Comment: I think it will not be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario of LINQ-to-SQL for Windows Phone, it is not possible to add tables to the `DataContext` after it is initialized. In my case, solution was to accept the whole `DataContext` from the user of library as follows:

First, you provide a base class from which users can derive.

```
public class DataContextBase : DataContext
{
    public DataContextBase(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    { }

    //Tables for library's internal workings.
    public Table<SyncTimeStamp> SyncTimeStamps;
}
```

Then user can pass the derived class while configuring the library. Library may accept this is method parameter:

```
public async void ConfigureSQLCE<T>(T mainDataContext) where T : DataContextBase
{   
    //Do whatever with it. MainDB is a dynamic here!
    MainDB = mainDataContext;
}
```