# Create inheritable LINQ-to-SQL mapable class

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I am building a library for Windows Phone 8 which requires local databases. For obvious reasons, user of the library is going to create a mappable LINQ-to-SQL class with appropriate `[Table]`s and `[Column]`s. However, To in every such class, I need a few more columns for internal functioning of the library. The idea was that I would include a base class in the library which will have members corresponding to the required columns. The user would simply inherit from this class, add his own members and use that class as final LINQ-to-SQL map.

So far, my base class looks like this:

```
//Class to contain all the essential members
[Table]
public class SyncableEntityBase : NotifyBase, ISyncableBase
{
    [Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime RemoteLastUpdated { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime LocalLastUpdated { get; set; }       
}
```

And the derived class, something like this:

```
[Table]
public class ToDoCategory : SyncableEntityBase
{
    private string _categoryName;
    [Column]
    public string CategoryName
    {
        get
        {
            return _categoryName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_categoryName != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("CategoryName");
                _categoryName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CategoryName");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _categoryColor;
    [Column]
    public string CategoryColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _categoryColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_categoryColor != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("CategoryColor");
                _categoryColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CategoryColor");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Idea is to have final class with the four essential columns and two added by user. According to MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399352%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I need to append `[InheritanceMapping]` which requires the inherited type. However, as I am building a library, I have no way to know what types (and how many) the user will derive from my base class. Is there any way around this? How?

Comment: maybe you can use this instead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2007/11/09/linq-to-sql-how-to-2-base-class-for-all-entities.aspx

Comment: @ErikEJ This approach basically enforces the user to implement properties. User still has to do the work which shouldn't be necessary as the properties should absolutely be there - without any change by user.
Secondly, I just wrote interface instead of an abstract class. How does it compare?

Comment: I think you are going for an impossible task, maybe use code generation approach? (I could help you there)

Comment: @ErikEJ I am okay with whatever approach works. The ultimate idea is to achieve the thing [here](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2013/06/08/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Service-to-SQLite-Data-Sync-for-Windows-Phone-and-Windows-RT-with-Portable-Class-Libraries.aspx) via a library. In the link above, the guy seems to be able to do what I'm doing quite happily using SQLite. Moreover, he's also got `CreateTable` method which could solve my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082512/creating-sql-server-ce-datacontext-with-tables-at-runtime).

Comment: Yes, but I think it will not be possible with SQL CE...

Comment: @ErikEJ Could you provide more details about the code generation approach? Also, if I were to go for the suggestion you provided, what would be better in my case? Interface or abstract class?

Comment: Have a look at my SQL CE Toolbox, it can add columns as required to an existing database, and generate code.